# get time difference from childs

Tags: mysql, sql, date, laravel, eloquent

I have the following structure

```
----------
presences
----------
id
started
ended
user_id

---------
breaks
---------
id
presence_id
started
ended
```

I need to create an SQL query that returns me the following information

`presence_id user_id presence_time breaks_time`

where presence time is (presence.ended - presence-started) - sum of (break.ended - break.started) of all the breaks related to the presence

Is there an efficient way to get this information with an sql query?

If you know how to do it in eloquent it would be even better :D

Thank you so much!

Comment: is your started and ended a timestamp or a datetime?

Comment: they are a timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/650a2/3

```
SELECT p.id presence_id,
    p.user_id,
    (p.ended-p.started) presence_time , 
    SUM(b.ended-b.started) breaks_time
FROM presences p
LEFT JOIN breaks b
ON p.id = b.presence_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

**UPDATE** Same query grouped by user_id:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ce21/1

```
SELECT 
    sub_total.user_id,
    SUM(sub_total.presence_time) , 
    SUM(sub_total.breaks_time)
FROM (
SELECT p.id presence_id,
    p.user_id,
    (p.ended-p.started) presence_time , 
    SUM(b.ended-b.started) breaks_time
FROM presences p
LEFT JOIN breaks b
ON p.id = b.presence_id
GROUP BY p.id) sub_total
GROUP BY sub_total.user_id
```

Comment: why? it works if mysql can do minus `-` operation between those 2 fields. Since it is not set in OP, i set it to int, but you can try whatever you want. Query will not change a lot, it is just type casting.

Comment: Thank yo so much! it worked, check my own answer to see my final query with timestamps

Answer (score 1):

If your `started` and `ended` are stored as `datetime` or `timestamp`, then you can easily do the calculation and find the data in minutes.
The following example will be useful when someone taking multiple short breaks through out the working hours.

Later in the application level you can convert the minutes to hour. Here is how you can do in mysql

```
mysql> select * from presence ;
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| id   | started             | ended               | user_id |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
|    1 | 2015-01-01 09:00:00 | 2015-01-01 18:00:00 |      10 |
|    2 | 2015-01-01 09:20:00 | 2015-01-01 18:04:00 |      11 |
|    3 | 2015-01-01 09:10:00 | 2015-01-01 18:30:00 |      12 |
|    4 | 2015-01-02 09:23:10 | 2015-01-02 18:10:00 |      10 |
|    5 | 2015-01-02 09:50:00 | 2015-01-02 19:00:00 |      11 |
|    6 | 2015-01-02 09:10:00 | 2015-01-02 18:36:30 |      12 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from breaks ;
+------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | presence_id | started             | ended               |
+------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 |           1 | 2015-01-01 12:00:00 | 2015-01-01 12:20:30 |
|    2 |           1 | 2015-01-01 15:46:30 | 2015-01-01 15:54:26 |
|    3 |           2 | 2015-01-01 11:26:30 | 2015-01-01 11:34:23 |
|    4 |           2 | 2015-01-01 14:06:45 | 2015-01-01 14:10:20 |
|    5 |           2 | 2015-01-01 16:01:10 | 2015-01-01 16:14:57 |
|    6 |           3 | 2015-01-01 12:11:20 | 2015-01-01 12:40:05 |
|    7 |           3 | 2015-01-01 17:01:10 | 2015-01-01 17:24:21 |
|    8 |           4 | 2015-01-02 12:50:00 | 2015-01-02 13:40:00 |
|    9 |           5 | 2015-01-02 12:20:00 | 2015-01-02 13:05:30 |
|   10 |           5 | 2015-01-02 17:03:00 | 2015-01-02 17:20:00 |
|   11 |           6 | 2015-01-02 12:16:50 | 2015-01-02 12:58:30 |
+------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)



select
p.id as presence_id,
p.user_id,
timestampdiff(minute,started,ended) - b.break_time as presence_time,
b.break_time from presence p
left join (
 select
 presence_id,
 coalesce(sum( timestampdiff(minute,started,ended ) ),0) as break_time
 from breaks
 group by presence_id
)b
on b.presence_id = p.id

+-------------+---------+---------------+------------+
| presence_id | user_id | presence_time | break_time |
+-------------+---------+---------------+------------+
|           1 |      10 |           513 |         27 |
|           2 |      11 |           501 |         23 |
|           3 |      12 |           509 |         51 |
|           4 |      10 |           476 |         50 |
|           5 |      11 |           488 |         62 |
|           6 |      12 |           525 |         41 |
+-------------+---------+---------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alex I got it working, my final query is the following (using timestamps)

```
SELECT *,
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(p.ended,p.started)) as presence_time,
    sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(b.ended,b.started))) as breaks_time

FROM presences p
left join presences_breaks b on b.presence_id = p.id
group by p.id
```

Comment: Since you didn't provide fiddle, I am not sure that your query will work :-) `sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(p.ended,p.started))) as presence_time,` is wrong. if you will test it with any data set where you have 2 breaks or more - you will see that presense time wil multiply as many times as many breakes you have. so it must be `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(p.ended,p.started)) as presence_time,`

Comment: You are right! the sum for presence_time was multipling!

Comment: what about if now I want to group by user_id?